# How can I stop Excel From Updating Links When Copy and Pasting Cells Linked to Other Workbooks?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

**Summary of the problem:** I would like excel NOT to link to the spreadsheets links I'm copy and pasting until I have the entire spreadsheet setup.

**Overview:** I have a worksheet that acts to aggregate a bunch of data from a number of additional workbooks, and when I'm adding a new column of data I generally copy a previously linked column and then do a find and replace to get the different dataset from the same columns (i.e. in the first column I'm pulling in named cell `Data1` from each linked workbook and I want to pull in the named cell `Data2` so I would copy/paste the `Data1` column and then find and replace the new column to get named cell `Data2` from each workbook)

The issue is, that I don't have just one workbook that does this, I have many and have to build new ones regularly and when I copy and paste a linked file Excel lags as it pastes in the new column and I guess starts linking to the workbooks. I would like it to not do this and allow me to get all my columns setup (it does this for each one), find and replaced, and then I can update the links. Kind of like how if you set your calculations to manual you can setup a bunch of different formulas and then hit <kbd>F9</kbd> to update everything all at once. Unfortunately setting Excel to manual calculate doesn't stop it from going through the process of linking to the named cells for each workbook when a whole column is copy and pasted and there's significant lag time when I'm setting up a new workbook.

If anyone knows a good way to solve this issue, it would save me a great deal of time when I'm setting up new aggregation work books.

**Better Example...Maybe** Also just for clarity when I say linked cell I mean a cell that's formula is `C:\Some folder\someworkbook.xlsm'NamedCellNumberOne` and I'll have a Column with a bunch of these to the `NamedCellNumberOne` in a number of different workbooks and I want to copy and paste that and bring in `NamedCellNumberTwo` in another column. This is when it lags and is slowing down building these things out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the volume of the data you are copying, this may not be a viable option but...

You could copy the formula text for all of the linked cell without the equals sign with minimal slowdown and, once everything is in place, use CONCATENATE or search and replace to add the equals sign to the beginning of all of those text strings then let it crank out all of those links at once.

Let's say all of the data is in a range adjacent to "NamedCellNumberOne" You could paste "C:\Some folder\someworkbook.xlsm'NamedCellNumberOne" in the first cell then drag the corner of the cursor to "fill series" as needed. Once that is done, search all instances of "C:\Some folder\" and replace them with "=C:\Some folder\" to create all the formulas at once.

Answer (score 1):

That is a long question and if I understand it correctly, this is what you are asking for.

Go to `File Tab > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > External Content`. Then under `Security settings for Workbook Links` choose to be prompted or disable them until you are ready.

[image]

Comment: Hey Charlie thanks for the reply, Unfortunately I've already checked this box. In addition, there are settings in the Options ->Advanced section where you can disable "Update Links to Other Documents" and "Ask to Update Automatic Links" both of which I've unchecked with no success in alleviating the issue

Comment: Have you taken a look at this? [Control when external references (links) are updated](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/control-when-external-references-links-are-updated-HP010342302.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft's [Control when external references (links) are updated](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Control-when-external-references-links-are-updated-87861952-ca9d-4d2a-a986-4d672c908d0d):

> **Break a link to a source**
>
> **Important**    When you break a link to a source, all formulas that use
>   the source are converted to their current value. For example, the link
>   =SUM([Budget.xls]Annual!C10:C25) would be converted to =45. Because this action cannot be undone, you may want to save a version of the
>   file.
>
> 1. On the Data tab, in the Connections group, click Edit Links.
> 2. In the Source list, click the link that you want to break.
>
>    To select multiple linked objects, hold down CTRL and click each
>      linked object.
>
>    To select all links, press CTRL+A.
> 3. Click Break Link.
> 4. If the link used a defined name, the name is not automatically
>      removed. You may want to delete the name as well.
>
>    **How to delete a name**
>
>    - On the Formulas tab, in the Named Cells group, click Name Manager.
>    - In the Name column, click the name that you want to delete, and then
>        click Delete.
> 5. If you use an external data range, a parameter of a query may also use
>      data from another workbook. You may want to check for and remove any
>      of these types of links.

Comment: Please note that attribution is required when you copy content from another site. Thanks.

Comment: While this does explain how to break the link, it is permanent. I believe that the OP wants to _temporarily_ stop updates.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `$`. Instead of `=A1`, use `=$A$1`.